# Как получить поле типа группа, вложенное в другое такое же поле в ACF?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Есть сайт с кучей таких полей вложенных одно в другое. Если верхний уровень можно вывести без проблем, то с теми которые вложены в него все немного сложнее. Посмотрел инструкции, но для таких случаев не нашел ничего полезного. Вот одна из них https://only-to-top.ru/blog/programming/2019-05-11-vyvod-proizvolnyh-polej-acf.html

Comment: Можете получить при помощи `get_sub_field()`. Вложенный `have_rows()` тоже вроде должен работать. `то с теми которые вложены в него все немного сложнее` -- или опишите чем конкретно это сложнее.